# Using window function to retrieve values from a column depending on another

Tags: mysql, window-functions

In a dataframe like below:

```
id    date      product
1   2010-02-01     c
1   2010-02-02     v
1   2010-02-03     d
1   2010-02-04     g
2   2010-02-03     h
2   2010-02-04     w
2   2010-02-05     t
2   2010-02-06     d
3   2010-02-04     x
3   2010-02-05     f
3   2010-02-06     x
```

I want to add another column giving the product that the user used in the minimum date. So it needs to be like below:

```
id    date      product  early_product
1   2010-02-01     c         c
1   2010-02-02     v         c
1   2010-02-03     d         c
1   2010-02-04     g         c
2   2010-02-03     h         h
2   2010-02-04     w         h
2   2010-02-05     t         h
2   2010-02-06     d         h
3   2010-02-04     x         x
3   2010-02-05     f         x
3   2010-02-06     x         x
```

I know I need to use the window function and started with the one below. But that will provide me the earliest date per user. I need to find the product used in the earliest day for user:

```
min(date) over (partition by id) as earliest_date
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question already?

Comment: I did but someone tagged it as duplicate although it wasn't.

Comment: That was me, and I've done it again. You want the product from the row with the lowest date. The other question explains how to get that row by user.

Comment: But I want to solve it with a window function for learning purposes and also my actual query is much larger than this one so it won't be efficient to use that way.

Comment: The other question has answers using window functions.

Comment: What does 'data frame' mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FIRST_VALUE as Window function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `date` Date,
>   `product` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `date`, `product`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2010-02-01', 'c'),
>   ('1', '2010-02-02', 'v'),
>   ('1', '2010-02-03', 'd'),
>   ('1', '2010-02-04', 'g'),
>   ('2', '2010-02-03', 'h'),
>   ('2', '2010-02-04', 'w'),
>   ('2', '2010-02-05', 't'),
>   ('2', '2010-02-06', 'd'),
>   ('3', '2010-02-04', 'x'),
>   ('3', '2010-02-05', 'f'),
>   ('3', '2010-02-06', 'x');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `id`, `date`, `product` 
> , FIRST_VALUE(`product`) OVER(PARTITION BY `id` ORDER BY `date` ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) minproduct
> FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | product | minproduct
> -: | :--------- | :------ | :---------
>  1 | 2010-02-01 | c       | c         
>  1 | 2010-02-02 | v       | c         
>  1 | 2010-02-03 | d       | c         
>  1 | 2010-02-04 | g       | c         
>  2 | 2010-02-03 | h       | h         
>  2 | 2010-02-04 | w       | h         
>  2 | 2010-02-05 | t       | h         
>  2 | 2010-02-06 | d       | h         
>  3 | 2010-02-04 | x       | x         
>  3 | 2010-02-05 | f       | x         
>  3 | 2010-02-06 | x       | x
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b1427278f7ff83c458fb5fb6703d7383)*

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am getting this error: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;

Comment: lokks like you use aws i changed my answer